# How to properly make mock throw an error in Jest?

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphql, jestjs

I'm testing my GraphQL api using Jest.

I'm using a separate test suit for each query/mutation

I have 2 tests (each one in a separate test suit) where I mock one function (namely, Meteor's `callMethod`) that is used in mutations.

```
  it('should throw error if email not found', async () => {
    callMethod
      .mockReturnValue(new Error('User not found [403]'))
      .mockName('callMethod');

    const query = FORGOT_PASSWORD_MUTATION;
    const params = { email: 'user@example.com' };

    const result = await simulateQuery({ query, params });

    console.log(result);

    // test logic
    expect(callMethod).toBeCalledWith({}, 'forgotPassword', {
      email: 'user@example.com',
    });

    // test resolvers
  });
```

When I `console.log(result)` I get

```
{ data: { forgotPassword: true } }
```

This behaviour is not what I want because in `.mockReturnValue` I throw an Error and therefore expect `result` to have an error object

Before this test, however, another is ran

```
 it('should throw an error if wrong credentials were provided', async () => {
    callMethod
      .mockReturnValue(new Error('cannot login'))
      .mockName('callMethod');
```

And it works fine, the error is thrown

I guess the problem is that mock doesn't get reset after the test finishes.
In my `jest.conf.js` I have   `clearMocks: true`

Each test suit is in a separate file, and I mock functions before tests like this:

```
import simulateQuery from '../../../helpers/simulate-query';

import callMethod from '../../../../imports/api/users/functions/auth/helpers/call-accounts-method';

import LOGIN_WITH_PASSWORD_MUTATION from './mutations/login-with-password';

jest.mock(
  '../../../../imports/api/users/functions/auth/helpers/call-accounts-method'
);

describe('loginWithPassword mutation', function() {
...
```

**UPDATE**

When I substituted `.mockReturnValue` with `.mockImplementation` everything worked out as expected:

```
callMethod.mockImplementation(() => {
  throw new Error('User not found');
});
```

But that doesn't explain why in another test `.mockReturnValue` works fine...

Comment: It looks like your mock is *returning* an error object, not _throwing_ it. Without seeing your code that you are testing, I can only share the experience I had. I forgot to mock a function called in my mutation, which caused an error to be thrown unintentionally. Perhaps there is something similar happening for you?

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Change `.mockReturnValue` with `.mockImplementation`:

```
    yourMockInstance.mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error();
    });
```

in case you want to assert

```
   test('the fetch fails with an error', () => {
     return expect(fetchData()).rejects.toMatch('error');
   });
```

If it's a promise you can also to .rejects [www.jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#resolves--rejects](http://www.jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#resolves--rejects)

Comment: cool. How to handle it and make and assert?

Comment: it throws the error but then the test fails because it has thrown an error. how do we assert?

Answer (score 45):

For promises, can use https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvaluevalue

```
test('async test', async () => {
  const asyncMock = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error('Async error'));

  await asyncMock(); // throws "Async error"
});
```

For testing that error was thrown or not, can use https://eloquentcode.com/expect-a-function-to-throw-an-exception-in-jest

```
const func = () => {
  throw new Error('my error')
}
it('should throw an error', () => {
    expect(func).toThrow()
})
```

Comment: You would also need a try and catch in your expect otherwise it would not assert correctly. Can you please improve your answer or reply if I am missing something.

Comment: @MGDeveloper we dont need try-catch while unit testing and using toThrow() (https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror). If you try that in your tests, it should work. Can also test in here : https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-playground-forked-euewe?file=/src/sum.test.js:210-217 (sandbox content is transient though). I did edit the terminology from "handling" to "testing" if that was confusing

Comment: I found the mockRejectedValue helpful in the case that the asynchronous unit I was testing handled the exception thrown in a specific way that I wanted to test, therefore in that case a catch or toThrow() would not be needed.

Answer (score 19):

For Angular + Jest:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

yourMockInstance.mockImplementation(() => {
  return throwError(new Error('my error message'));
});
```

Comment: Technically this isn't a `throw` in the pure JS sense. You are configuring the mock to return a RXJS observable object which immediately emits an error notification. Still, maybe handy for folks to see here. The accepted answer certainly *will* make a mock throw an error. In all cases.

Comment: Only returning `throw Error` should be enough:  `yourMockInstance.mockImplementation(() => throwError('my error message'));`

Comment: Actually using `mockReturnValue` is enough:  `mockInstance.mockReturnValue(throwError(() => new Error('my error message')))`

Answer (score 2):

make sure to add `throw new Error('Network error or something')` either in `catch` block or conditionally.

```
import fetchApi from '../src'

it("should throw error", async () => {
    const errorMessage: string = "Network Error";
    
    (axios.post as jest.Mock).mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error(errorMessage));
    
    expect(async () => await fetchApi()).rejects.toThrow(
          errorMessage
    );
});
```