# How to unit test nested function in node js?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a function for which I am writing unit test but that function is calling another function and there I am not able to mock/stub that function.

for example :

```
function getValue( param1, param2, callback){
    getData(param1, param3).then( response) => {
         return callback();
    }, (err) => {
         return callback();
    });
}
```

So I don't know how to mock `getData()` function.

Comment: Where is `getData` defined ?

Comment: `getData` is defined in some other file which I am importing.

Comment: Then ask the question accordingly, There's no way to mock getData if it's random function, only it's an import.

Comment: Just to be complete, it **is** possible to mock `getData` even if it is a random function in the same file, but it must be **exported** and it must be called using the **module export**.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770749/10149510) for an ES6 version, a Node.js module would export `getData` like this: `exports.getData = getData;` and then call it within `getValue` like this: `exports.getData(...)`)

Comment: hey @brian-lives-outdoors getData is being exported.

Comment: I'm aware of that (and that's how I coded my answer below), just pointing out that it's possible to mock `getData` even if it *isn't* exported since an earlier comment made it sound like that wasn't possible.  @AtulKumar

Comment: Thanks for responding @brian-lives-outdoors, I am testing your code and will update it that work or not in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example that demonstrates what you are trying to do:

lib.js

```js
function getData(param1, param2) {
  return fetch('someUrl');  // <= something that returns a Promise
}

exports.getData = getData;
```

code.js

```js
const lib = require('./lib');

export function getValue(param1, param2, callback) {
  return lib.getData(param1, param2).then(response => {
    callback(response);
  }).catch(err => {
    callback(err);
  });
}

exports.getValue = getValue;
```

code.test.js

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');

const lib = require('./lib');
const { getValue } = require('./code');

describe('getValue', () => {
  it('should do something', async () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(lib, 'getData');
    stub.resolves('mocked response');

    const callback = sinon.spy();
    await getValue('val1', 'val2', callback);

    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(stub, 'val1', 'val2');  // Success!
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(callback, 'mocked response');  // Success!
  });
});
```

---

**Update**

OP added in the comments that they can't use `async / await` and are exporting the function using `module.exports = getData;`.

In that case the module export **is** the function and the entire module needs to be mocked with something like [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#readme).

The assertions should be done in a `then` callback and the test should return the resulting `Promise` so `mocha` knows to wait for it to resolve.

Updated example:

lib.js

```js
function getData(param1, param2) {
  return fetch('someUrl');  // <= something that returns a Promise
}

module.exports = getData;
```

code.js

```js
const getData = require('./lib');

function getValue(param1, param2, callback) {
  return getData(param1, param2).then(response => {
    callback(response);
  }).catch(err => {
    callback(err);
  });
}

module.exports = getValue;
```

code.test.js

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('getValue', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub();
    stub.resolves('mocked response');

    const getValue = proxyquire('./code', { './lib': stub });

    const callback = sinon.spy();
    return getValue('val1', 'val2', callback).then(() => {
      sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(stub, 'val1', 'val2');  // Success!
      sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(callback, 'mocked response');  // Success!
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey I am using `module.exports = getData` also async() is not working in node js 6 and as of  now it is throwing following error `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property getData`. Please respond . Thanks

Comment: I added an update with an example that works with those constraints.  @ankuselfie

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` this what I am getting. Also actual function is being called.

Comment: hey @brian-lives-outdoors this is not working, it is still not stubbing 'getData` function. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValue( param1, param2, callback){
    getData(param1, param3).then( response) => {
         callback(response);
    });
}

getvalue(param1, param2, function(error, response)) {
   console.log(response)
}
```

It might help you.