# JS - Mocking an uninitialized class method inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocking

Lets say I have this code below and I want to test `someFunc()` but I want to mock the `doSomething()` function? How can I do it in a test when the `SomeClass` is initialized only inside the `someFunc()` itself and not in the test?

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(element){
    this.element = element
  }
  
  doSomething(element){
    ...
  }
}

function someFunc() {
  const newClass = new SomeClass()
  newClass.doSomething() // I want this to get to the mocked function
}
```

I am using jest,
please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try some testing frameworks, most of them provide spies which allow you to mock specific functions for given classes.

For example, you can try Jasmine - https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html
Where you would do something like

```
spyOn(newClass, 'doSomething').and.returnValue(42);
```

Comment: But the newClass is not initialized in the test. Will it still work?

Comment: @DanielleVardi then I would maybe consider mocking your named function completely, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755439/how-to-mock-imported-named-function-in-jest-when-module-is-unmocked

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to mock es6 class in Jest: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks

Comment: But my problem is different. I dont have a problem mocking a class that was initialized in test. My problem is mocking an uninitiliazed class

Comment: Then `newClass.doSomething = jest.fn()` should work.